# How to insert node js script in a html file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have started a POST server using node Js. I want to access the POST service through html file.

```
<html>
   <body>

<script type="text/javascript">  
function PostMethod(){  
var http = require('http');

//The url we want is: 'www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
var options = {
  host: 'localhost',
  port:8081,
  path: '/',
 method: 'POST'
};

callback = function(response) {
  var str = '';

  //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });

  //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
  response.on('end', function () {
    alert(str);
  });
}

http.request(options, callback).end();
}  
</script>  
<form>  
Enter No:<input type="text" id="number" name="number"/><br/>  
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="PostMethod()"/>  
</form>

   </body>
</html>
```

This is not working. But iF I seperatly run the script in node js, the post reply I am getting

Comment: node code isn't meant to run at the client side. its server side (backend)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use node modules directly in browser. You can try this one.
https://github.com/substack/http-browserify

Have a look at this. http://browserify.org/

Comment: Other common alternatives would be a simple plain old HTML form (no JavaScript needed) or jQuery.